# Why do we exclude the quark condensate in the OPE?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-chromodynamics

In every QCD paper I open people say that in the OPE, the lowest order non-trivial condensate is the gluon condensate, whose dimensions are 4. Nonetheless, I knowof the existence of the quark condensate, whose dimensions are 3. Why is this one excluded?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this is right. The leading operator is the OPE of the nucleon currents is the chiral condensate, see Belyaev and Ioffe (1982),
http://inspirehep.net/record/178457?ln=en.

Comment: you are probably right. Maybe there is a reason beyond the quark condensate never appearing in the OPE for the papers I have checked to ignore it.

Comment: the chiral condensate violates chiral symmetry, and there are some correlators where only $m\langle\bar{q}q\rangle$ appears. The latter is also RG invariant.